# wpf shader template

Tags: wpf, shader

I used the shader templates given through Greg Schechter's blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2008/08/11/a-visualstudio-buildtask-and-project-and-item-templates-for-writing-shadereffects.aspx

It was all simple to add the wpf shader templates and create the project. I'm also able to see that the shader is working through the visual studio 2008 designer when editing my xaml. But I get this error when I run my program:
**Cannot find type 'ShaderEffectLibrary1.Effect1'. The assembly used when compiling might be different than that used when loading and the type is missing.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your top level project (for the GUI) also has a reference to the `ShaderEffectLibrary`. I ran across a similar problem today where I was referencing a third-party library from within my WPF user control library. It built fine, but then I would receive a similar exception at execution time. It turned out that adding a reference to the third-party library from the top level project resolved the exception.